# issue when building module using cmake

Tags: cmake, box2d, cmake-gui

i am trying to build box2D using cmake. When i click configure (and selecting my version of visual studio) cmake starts working but it finnishes with the error message:

> You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library glfw without any source files.
>   This typically indicates a problem with your CMakeLists.txt file
>
> Configuring done

What is the issue and how can i solve it? Where is the CMakeLists.txt located  and how can i edit it to build without errors?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably an error in this library. Try another version or post a bug.

It means that according to this file, a library should be created without source files (an empty library), which is probably bug.

`CMakeLists.txt` is located in every cmake source directory, make sure you're choosing the right directory.

Comment: do you mean i should try another version of cmake? or box2d

Comment: @Bonbin, box2d, that where the bug is.

Comment: but there is only one version of box2d

Comment: @Bonbin, there are more than only one: https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D
Try master. If if isn't working, post a bug.

Comment: i am using master this whole time, but ill post a bug